# Preventing Ajax race conditions in AngularJS?

Tags: ajax, angularjs-scope, race-condition

If I make two requests to `$http` requests in AngularJS whose success will update the same `$scope`, is there a standard way to track this and prevent out-of-date changes resulting from Ajax calls returning in the wrong order?  Similarly a `$scope` update may be triggered by user interaction.  E.g.:

1. AJAX request triggered
2. User interaction changes `$scope.some_value`
3. AJAX response received, and wants to change `$scope.some_value`

in `3`, the change to `$scope.some_value` should be rejected, otherwise the value of `$scope.some_value` may be inconsistent.

I have searched the Angular docs, and stackoverflow, but found nothing relating to this.

One approach I am considering is to decorate the `$http` service, and assign an incremental ID to each outgoing request.  I will also maintain a map of scope objects to request IDs, recording which request has changed this scope item.  The last update's request ID could then be checked to make sure that it is less than the request ID which subsequently wants to update the scope variable.

However, this approach seems tricky to implement, and will not account for changes caused by user interaction.

Is there a standard pattern for dealing with this problem?

Comment: use the `promise` returned from the `ajax` call to do things in sequence.

Comment: What guarantees the ordering of promise fulfilment?

Comment: sorry, i didn't read the question 100% I now see you are speaking about requests happening multiple times...the solution to this is to send the dateTime or just an int (call number)...Then on server response if the number is lower than your previous request for that user just ignore it

Comment: @abc123 that's what I was thinking, but how does that also cope with user interaction?  And you're implying that there is no built-in handling for this in angular - is that the case?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of but i'm new to angular as well.